# Not working getChildCount() in android

Tags: android, view

I have one relative layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/phone_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/phoneno" android:layout_width="159px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Phone"
                android:textSize="18sp" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/phone_type"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phone_type" >
            </EditText>
            <Button android:id="@+id/phone_type" android:layout_width="92px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Home"
                android:layout_below="@+id/add_phone"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
            </Button>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/phone_label"
                android:layout_width="242px" android:layout_height="39px"
                android:text="Phone" android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
            </TextView>
            <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000" android:id="@+id/add_phone" android:onClick="managePhoneType"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/add"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginTop="5px"></ImageButton>
            <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000" android:id="@+id/remove_phone" android:onClick="managePhoneType"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/close"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/phoneno" android:layout_marginTop="8px"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageButton>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Now when i am trying to get all child of relative layout it is not returning  all.

i am using getChildCount() method like this

```
for(int i = 0; i<(r.getChildCount()); i++){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            Integer.toString(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

this code toasting only three child.

please help me what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Have you tried putting in logs. You may not know if the toats keep coming on top of each other.

Comment: No i did not but i used code in same for loop for removing view dynamically, and its removing only 3 view

Comment: Put more code up. The way you get the r variable. There may something small causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you. i also removed Toast from the code and put Log but its printing only three times. I am not getting what actually is problem.

Comment: You didnt put the code up. In case where code just doesnt behave right, I close and reopen eclipse and clean the project. Sometimes it just fixes it self that way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getCount()` instead of `getChildCount()` ... it worked for me. For more information you can check this .. [Android: Difference between getCount() and getChildCount() in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242800/android-difference-between-getcount-and-getchildcount-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the limitation is in the Toast implementation, maybe it has a buffer for only 3 messages.

I would use:

```
for(int i = 0; i<(r.getChildCount()); i++){
    System.out.println("!!! child#" + i + "=" + r.getChildAt(i));
}
```

You can see the printlines in the eclipse as well (in the logcat view), or (what I prefer) from a shell, by simply executing "adb logcat"