# Android: Difference between getCount() and getChildCount() in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

What is difference between `getCount()` and `getChildCount()` in `ListView`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`getCount()` returns you a count of items in Adapter (total in list), `getChildCount()` is a `ViewGroup` method that returns you number of subviews. `ListView` actively reuses views so if your list has 1000 items `getCount()` will return 1000, `getChildCount()` - around 10 or so...

Comment: up vote for this answer, for I've been stupid enough to do `listview.getChildAt(getCount() -1)` and get null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

`getCount()` is the number of items in the adapter while `getChildCount()` refers to the ViewGroup's method that returns the number of the views that this view contains.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter there is one Method `getChildrenCount();`that decide how many child you want to create.

```
  @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }
```