# listview count vs adapter count in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

Why do `listview.getChildCount()` and `adapter.getCount()` return different values? I have an onScroll method and from within it, if I call the methods above, each return different values. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242800/android-difference-between-getcount-and-getchildcount-in-listview)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ListView.getChildCount()` returns the number of `Views` on the screen. `Adapter`s `getCount()` returns the total number of objects in your list.

[getChildCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount%28%29)

[getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getCount%28%29)

You might have 50 `String`s in say an `ArrayAdapter` but only 10 are drawn on the screen at the current moment so your `ListView` count will be 10 but your `Adapter` count will be 50.

Comment: If I do `listview.getChildAt(index)` must `index` be `[0,listView.getChildCount() )` or could index be anything between `[0,adapter.getCount() )`?

Comment: `[0,listView.getChildCount() )`. Otherwise you could get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because, like my example illustrates, you may have more items in your `List` than are currently in your `ListView`

Comment: Now, you could do the other way but you would need to wrap in a `try/catch` to catch the `IOB Exception`

Answer (score 2):

`adapter.getCount()` returns total objects count contained in it. `listView.getChildCount()` return number of views showed in this listview. 
Adapter uses caching mechanism, and a lot of views are reused, that's why it's number differs from that shown in `adapter.getCount()`