# Android ListView child could is not updated

Tags: android, listview

I am working with a ListView. I add 10 elements to it at the beginning, and add elements on click. My problem is that the child count is not updated.

```
mItems = new ArrayList<String>();
mItems.add("Diary of a Wimpy Kid 6: Cabin Fever");
...
mItems.add("Death Comes to Pemberley");
// 10 items
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mItems);

mListView = (RefreshableListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After that, at some point, I have:

```
mItems.add(result);
invalidateViews();
```

The new item is shown, but the `getChildCount()` still returns 10.
I need that call to return the right value, because at some point I need to learn if the last element is shown using this:

```
if (this.getLastVisiblePosition() == this.getChildCount())
```

In that check, I have `this.getLastVisiblePosition()` = 11 and `this.getChildCount()` = 10.
How is it possible that the last shown child position is bigger than the child count?

Adding multiple elements, I eventually get to a 15 to 10, so it's not a one-time occurence.

Any thoughts will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have eventually found the answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242800/android-difference-between-getcount-and-getchildcount-in-listview). I made a coufusion between `getChildCount()` that returns the number of children views of the view group (the number of views shown) and it was always 10 because 10 elements were displayed at once and `getCount()`
that returns the actual size of the adapter (total number of elements in the list).

I will mark this answer as the correct one as soon as I am allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

Add items to adapter then use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I tried your solution, but getChildCount() still returns the old value