# Disabling children of framelayout that contains a scrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a custom `FrameLayout` that contains a scroll view as one of its elements.
I want to disable the children of the scrollview and it doesnt seem to be working

I am calling this method in onLayout of the FrameLayout

```
private void disableDescendants(ViewGroup v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (v.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup) {
                disableDescendants((ViewGroup) v.getChildAt(i));
            }
            v.setEnabled(false);
            v.setFocusable(false);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        }
    }
```

yet all the `EditTextss` in `ScrollView` , and the `ScrollView` itself don't seem to be disabled.
I can click on them to bring the keyboard up.

How can i make them disabled?

Comment: paste your layout code!@!

Answer (score 0):

Why getChildCount() might not work : [Android: Difference between getCount() and getChildCount() in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242800/android-difference-between-getcount-and-getchildcount-in-listview)

Try this :

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
for ( int i = 0; i < scrollView.getChildCount();  i++ ){
    View view = scrollView.getChildAt(i);
    view.setEnabled(false); 
}
```

Comment: my method is not doing that?

Comment: Does seem like it. But I don't think you need to go deep down into everything (using recursion) to disable the views. This is a code I had used and it did work.

Comment: i tried doing framelayout.setEnabled(false) but the children remain enabled for some reason...

Comment: Yeah, but I am pretty sure that a ScrollView recycles its views too and hence getChildCount() might suffer from the same problem.

Comment: scrollview doesnt recycle anything