# How to retrieve GridView object after notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, notifydatasetchanged

I have search on StackOverflow and other websites but no one can answer to my question.
I have a gridView with items. I have a button to add item to this gridView.Each element on the GridView is a relativeLayout with an Imageview and an EditText.

When i add item to the gridView using the button, I want to get my relativeLayout and request Focus on the editText to set a name on it.

Imagine i have 3 elements in my gridView.
I add element to my ArrayList and call adapter.notifiyDataSetChanged().
The new element is displayed on the grid but when i use getChildCount(), the gridView still has 3 children.

It cause problem because i want to request focus on the last added EditText.

How can i update my gridView object ?

Fragment :

```
//Get gridView
        final GridView gridCat = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridCategory);
        adapter = new GridCategoryAdapter(getActivity(), subcatList);
        gridCat.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridCat.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SubCategory subcat = subcatList.get(position);
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_middle, SubCategoryFragment.newInstance(subcat.getProducts(), subcat.getName()));
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        Button catAddButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.catAddButton);

        catAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "old size gridview : " + gridCat.getChildCount());
                subcatList.add(new SubCategory());
                Log.d(TAG, "new size list : " + subcatList.size());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d(TAG, "new size gridview : " + gridCat.getChildCount());
                //HERE : childCount is the same !
                RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) gridCat.getChildAt(gridCat.getChildCount()-1);
                rl.findViewById(R.id.subcatName).setFocusable(true);
                rl.findViewById(R.id.subcatName).setLongClickable(true);
                rl.findViewById(R.id.subcatName).requestFocus();
            }
        });
```

My Adapter :

```
public class GridCategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "com.zester.manager.ListViewSizeAndPriceAdapter";

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<SubCategory> listSubCat;

    private ViewHolder holder;


    public GridCategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SubCategory> values) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        listSubCat = values;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listSubCat.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listSubCat.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.subcat_view, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.SubCatName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subcatName);
            holder.imageSubCat = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageSubCatView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        SubCategory subCat = (SubCategory) getItem(position);
        if (subCat != null) {
            holder.SubCatName.setText(subCat.getName());
            holder.imageSubCat.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.subcat_default));
        }
        return convertView;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public EditText SubCatName;
        public ImageView imageSubCat;
    }

}
```

XML for each item on the gridview :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageSubCatView"
        android:src="@drawable/subcat_default"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subcatName"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Ex : Bières"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageSubCatView"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"/>
```

Thx a lot !

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242800/android-difference-between-getcount-and-getchildcount-in-listview

Comment: Thx a lot ! I'm so fool x)
But i have another problem. 
When i tried to get my RelativeLayout, null is return :
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) gridCat.getChildAt(gridCat.getCount()-1);

Comment: what is catAddButton supposed to do?

Comment: Add a new Category on the grid (at the end) and request Focus on the EditText associated. With this, user can write a name for this Category. So i want to get the RelativeLayout for this view and get my EditText. Am i clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`When i tried to get my RelativeLayout, null is return : RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) gridCat.getChildAt(gridCat.getCount()-1);`

I think your answer is this:

when you add

```
  subcatList.add(new SubCategory());
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to your code it is not guaranteed that new view for them has been created, because it is possible that your gridView has 100 children and you are just looking at children from 7 to 20 , so new child at index 100 has not yet inflated because the getView is called upon request in order to save memory so when there is no need to show the 100th child, why it must be called? so relativelayout for that child is null because it has not inflated.

in catAddButton  listener you must not touch any gridview item, because when the button click happens it first runs your listener then scrolls to the end of gridView so still you have problem, what sholud you do?

in class of SubCategory() put variable that indicates it has not shown for the first time. in getView of gridview each time you want to inflate new items look at that variable (in the list of your SubCategory at item list.get(position))  and for example if it is boolean toggle it to false so that means the new object is going to be seen by user. So in this way each time you are going to inflate the view you know that if it is the first time or not, if it is first time your boolean is true else it has already been false. if it is not first time remove focus else put focus by calling reqesFocuse.

Comment: Oh okay i get it! So i froce GRidview to scroll to the new item. So it seems work. My RelativeLayout is not Null. :) 
Thx.

Comment: hey look at my new answer!!

Comment: Does not work because when i add new item to the arrayList, i don't know if it will use a recycle view or not. So in one case, it will work and in the other not.

Comment: you do not care about recycling view , you just look at list.get(position).getFirstTimeView(); if it is true , it is the first time toggle it to false and continue else it has been seen ignore it. any recyling object is in my code? absolutely not. i just worked by your data not by their views

Comment: I found a solution. It is undoubtedly not opti but it work. 
I want to thank you for you patience ! :)