# application crash on converting whole list view data to array list in android

Tags: java, android

Hey guys I am facing an issue while converts list view (mList) data in the array list. This for loop is working fine till screen displays row's data, but it is not converting whole list view row's data which rows are  shown after scrolling. My application crash when loop comes to convert after scroll rows. I want to convert complete list view data into array list. Please tell me how can I resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
View v;

        for (int i = 0; i < mList.getCount(); i++) {

            v = mList.getChildAt(i);


            student_ID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.student_id);
            student_rollno = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.studentrllno);
            sudent_Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.student_name);
            sudent_FName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.father_name);
            status_s = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.status_spinner);

            student attendance = new student(student_ID.getText().toString(), student_rollno.getText().toString(), sudent_Name.getText().toString(),sudent_FName.getText().toString(), status_s.getSelectedItem().toString());
            student_submit_list.add(attendance);


        }
```

Error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: comsol.com.attendance, PID: 5752
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)'
>   on a null object reference

previous adapter:

```
student nmz = new student(newArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),
                        newArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rollno"),
                        newArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"),
                        newArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("father_name"),
                        "p");
                student_list.add(nmz);
```

Comment: You already have the listview items in the list attached to your adapter. You don't need to get them out of the listview

Comment: i have to again submit listview data into mysql server because it has a spinner which has attendance status.

Comment: thats why i am converting again listview into arraylist.

Comment: Can you post the code that attaches the list of items to the adapter?

Comment: in previous adapter i did not attached spinner so now am attaching spinner with this array list to submit attendance.

Comment: Since you are using a litview or a spinner with data, there is a list that you attached to its adapter. If there is not a list then the listview is empty

Comment: task:  i am fetching data from server and displaying into list view there is spinner in each row and am selecting any option (P, A, L) of spinner  after that there is is a button to submit whole list view data to sending again to server to submit attendance.

Comment: Don't you save the selection you make in the spinner by a listener in your adapter?

Comment: no, how can i save the spinner selection in my adapter? please give me link or sample code?

Comment: if you don't save it then if you scroll up or down the list the selection will be lost or it will change other items

Answer (score 0):

use

```
for (int i = 0; i < mList.getChildCount(); i++)
```

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10242841/4978849) for the difference between getCount and getChildCount

Comment: Thank you so much @George Arokiam you save my project. Once again thanks.

Comment: this is also geting only that rows data which are displays on screen. :(

Comment: I want to get all items (visible and invisible) from a ListView. But problem is that by this loop i can't get all items.  it is getting only that items which are showing on screen. It is not getting the items which are visible after scrolling.

Comment: I need to get complete listview data.

Comment: Okay then this approach is entirely wrong for what you are trying to achieve. 
Forget about your implementation. Let's try to refactor this. First tell me where do you get the information that you populate the list items from? Are you populating the list from an adapter?

Comment: please George help, how can i achieve this.